# How to get the overlap parts of polygon features in a same layer by QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, overlay

I have a polygon layer, some features are overlapped.
I want to get the overlapped part(s) and save them to another feature.
For example,
1 polygon(0 0, 2 0, 2 2, 0 2, 0 0)
and
2 polygon(1 1, 3 1, 3 3, 1 3, 1 1)
the result of 1 and 2
is polygon (1 1, 2 1, 2 2, 1 2, 1 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run "Polygon self-intersection" from SAGA Processing tools:

[image]

It returns a new layer, where intersecting parts of two features will get their original IDs as shown here:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried the solution, it worked well on splitting polygons, But it was a pity that there were some encoding errors on the table values of the result. Can we assign the encoding for SAGA or GRASS algorithms in QGIS?

Comment: @donkeychen you need to assign the encoding to the layer before running any tool. They should just take over this setting to the new layer. Depending on the datasource / filetype there are different ways to this. E.g. the encoding for CSVs needs be set while importing or for shapefiles you can set it within layerproperties->source.